# how to remove a element of a array by its index value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I need to remove a element of a array by its index value. I have the index value already I just need to splice it. The customSeriesIndexMatch is the index number that i need to remove from customSeriesSums.data

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qzk3sqs8/)

```
var dataPointSum = 101100;
console.log(customSeriesSums[0].data);

 // loop through customSeriesSums and match with dataPointSum
    var index = customSeriesSums[0].data.indexOf(dataPointSum);
    var customSeriesIndexMatch = index + 1
   console.log("DataPointSum : " + dataPointSum + " " + "Matched with customSeriesSum Index : " + customSeriesIndexMatch);

 // now I need to remove the customSeriesSums.data array by its index that equals customSeriesIndexMatch
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [splice docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

`customSeriesSums[0].data.splice( customSeriesIndexMatch,1 );`

Answer (score 3):

So just use [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) method:

```
customSeriesSums[0].data.splice( customSeriesIndexMatch, 1 );
```